# Add new ad network to Admob mediation group while testing

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I have an app out on Play Store with ads. I use Admob mediation to show ads from other ad networks. Right now, I only have Admob and Facebook Audience Network in the mediation group and I have the corresponding adapter for the FAN in the build.gradle. Now, I want to add some more ad networks to the mediation group.

If I add a new ad network to the mediation group, won't the production app start using that ad network as well right away even though, it doesn't have the corresponding adapter for the ad network in the APK. I guess my app won't crash but it won't be able to show the ad either. I didn't find any documentation around this topic.

So, I want to ask what is the process of adding a new ad network to the mediation such that I can avoid my production app using that ad network until I release the update to production.

Answer (score 0):

When you add new ad network adapter previous version of user won't be affected and when you add placement id of new ad network from Admob dashboard it will continue to show ads. 
Your app won't crash.

Comment: I understand that the app won't crash. I wanted to know does admob somehow know to not request an ad from the newly added ad network in the mediation group since the app doesn't have an adapter for it. For e.g. I add ADN1 and ADN2 to the mediation group and add the corresponding adapters and release an app. Now I add ADN3 to the same mediation group. The existing users will still hit the same mediation group but they don't have the adapter for ADN3 in their app. So, is that somehow handled and admob won't request ads from ADN3 for existing users till they have the new app?

Comment: Ad Network will check adapter as well as mediation group contains that ADN after correct configuration then only they request for the ad so your current app will not crash while you will add AND3 in Admob mediation group without giving any update.